# Servlet cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC project which uses hibernate with postgreSQL for saving data.
I have a JSP file, which calls the action to "/user/add" residing in controller. But the error I get is the servlet cannot be resolved. I have added the jar in libraries in the project structure. I am posting the controller and JSP code here. Kindly have a look.

user.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add"> </c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="user">
<table>
    <c:if test="${!empty user.first_Name}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                            <spring:message text="UserID:"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8" disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </c:if>
```

UserController

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/user/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("user") User p){
        if(p.getId() == 0){
            this.userService.addUser(p);
        } else {
            this.userService.updateUser(p);
        }
        return "redirect:/users";
    }
```

Catalina.out

```
Sep 17, 2014 11:44:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/akshay/apache-tomcat/webapps/WirTauschen-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 17 11:44:56 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 96 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 17 11:44:56 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/users],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.WirTauschen.UserController.listUsers(org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/user/add],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.WirTauschen.UserController.addPerson(com.WirTauschen.model.User)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.WirTauschen.UserController.editPerson(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/remove/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.WirTauschen.UserController.removeUser(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 914 ms
Sep 17, 2014 11:44:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /home/akshay/apache-tomcat/webapps/WirTauschen-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war has finished in 1,761 ms
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WirTauschen%2D1.0%2DSNAPSHOT/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_, user0_.first_Name as first_Na3_0_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_, user0_.password as password5_0_ from wirtausch2 user0_
Hibernate: insert into wirtausch2 (email, first_Name, last_name, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 17 11:44:56 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 17 11:44:56 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the problem is in your URL mapping, it should be `value="user/add"`.

Comment: When I use "user/add", it says, it cannot resolve the directory.

Comment: Could you please give the exact error message ? Or better the stacktrace ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : my mistake, see below

<del>You add the context path twice.</del>

`<c:url var="addAction" value="/user/add"> </c:url>` puts the full path (context path + servlet path) in `addAction`<del>, and you use it in `<form:form action=...>`, which also adds the context path.</del>

<del>You should use instead :</del>

<del>`<form:form action="/user/add" commandName="user" method="POST">`</del>

<del>You only need to use `<c:url .../>` if you use the path in a link `<a href="${addAction}"...>`</del>

I make confusion with the spring library for Velocity that I am used to and which directly knows about the servlet context. In true JSP, you have to use `<c:url ...>` to get the correct action url.

I really need the stacktrace to help you : I could do some tests and the problem is not where I thought.

Comment: Hello Serge, Well I guess your method works, atleast I don't get any errors atleast. But now I have Error 404 from Apache as to /user/add was not found. Why is the catalina log not showing anything surprises me.

Comment: Please find the catalina.out file in the public dropbox link as follows :  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1994132/catalina.out

Comment: Nice to you to give it all, but it is really too much, there are errors from different runs, errors related to database, to Tomcat bootstrap, etc. :-( What I need is only the error  that happens when you submit the form ...

Comment: Edited the post. Kindly have a look. Nothing is persisted in database. That is the main problem.

Comment: Well, it works now, but I still have the error that it cannot be resolved.

Comment: For the error in persisting in database, you try to insert a value with a NULL id. That is correct, but you must give a generator strategy to hibernate.

Comment: Did, as I said, it is saving data now, but the IDE still gives error that it cannot find the servlet /user/add, and when I see the catalina.out, it says, it was able to map /user/add.. I guess IDE issues. Thank you for all your help.